# Reading cache using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

This is Two questions:
1/ How can I read the cache stored by the browser if there's no permission restrictions?
2/ If the user browse into a website, is there a posibility of storing the page source code [HTML] in cache? (big website like youtube ..etc)

Thanks.

Comment: UM, and how would you access the cache??

Comment: That is my question.

Comment: You can't from a web page....unless a user manually goes and selects all the files on their computer for you to access with the HTML5 file api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no way to read the cache manually - it all happens behind the scenes, if there is cache.
2. Yes, you can store the website's source code to the browser cache, but only the client-side part - HTML/CSS/JS/images/fonts/etc. It's called [HTML5 Application Cache](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_app_cache.asp) and it consists in a simple manifest file, which instructs the browser to download certain files locally and next time load them instead of downloading again. This cache you can programmatically update. Keep in mind, though, that most browsers have a limit (usually 5MB) of how much data you can store.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know that we an storre cache with jQuery, but the question is Facebook ..etc do they cache the HTML/JS part ??

Comment: i made it as the right answer after 4 years, that's a little bit late :D lol

Comment: The HTML5 Application Cache [has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache), so it's being replaced by the [Cache API](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker).